# Undetermined registration of resources while migrating to Jersey 3.1.x

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

While migrating from *Tomcat 9.x*/*Jersey 2.x* to *Tomcat 10.1.x*/*Jersey 3.1.x* we are recognizing indetermined behaviour of registering resource classes when deploying a webapp as *.war* file. Our *.war* file contains

- different resource classes annotated with *@Provider* or *@Path*
- a custom *Application extends ResourceConfig* subclass to *register()* a subset of these resources that we actually want to use. We annotated the application class with *@ApplicationPath("/")* and have no servlet mapping in *web.xml*.

Now, when deploying (or redeploying) the *.war* file and do one subsequent request on a *@Path* annotated endpoint,

- in about 50% of the cases, *getClasses()* of our application returns only the subset of resource classes of our *.war* file that we have registered (as expected) (1), wheras
- in the other 50% of the cases, *getClasses()* returns *all* resource classes of our *.war* file (that's unexpected) (2)

In the current Jersey docs (https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/3.1.3/deployment.html), section 4.8.2.3.2, we found:

> If your custom Application subclass is packaged in the war, it defines
> which resources will be taken into account. If both getClasses() and
> getSingletons() methods return an empty collection, then ALL the root
> resource classes and providers packaged in the web application archive
> will be used, Jersey will automatically discover them by scanning the
> .war file. If any of the two mentioned methods - getClasses() or
> getSingletons() returns a non-empty collection, only those classes
> and/or singletons will be published in the JAX-RS application.

After putting some debug messages in our code and analyzing the tomcat log (*catalina.out*), we see that in the expected case (1) the application *configure()* method runs *before* any of the resource classes gets instanciated, whereas in the unexpected case (2) *configure()* runs *after* the initialization of some filter resource classes annotated with *@Provider*. It seems that the point in time at which *getClasses()* is called to check for an empty collection varies, leading to unexpected behaviour concerning the registration of the resource classes that gets finally added for the application and remains constant for subsequent requests.

For us, the behaviour looks undetermined and stops us from migration: Resources like authentication filters are a crucial part of our application and we have to rely on working properly, but currently, we can't.

**Our question is: How can we eliminate the unexpected behaviour?**

We thought about disabling the auto-discovering mode of resource classes being enabled by default. If there would be a way to turn of scanning for automatic *@Path* or *@Provider* annotations (and keep going on with scanning *@ApplicationPath* and *@WebListener*) it could be a workaround for us.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: After some testing I'm quite sure that the problem is due to the combination of _custom Application subclass_ and _no servlet defined in web.xml_. After removing the @ApplicationPath annotation and adding one of the web.xml sections below (see e. g. 4.8.2.3.2 of the Jersey docs) then everything works as expected. Maybe someone can check that and file a bug to the jersey team?

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>a.b.c.MyResourceConfig</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>a.b.c.MyResourceConfig</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Alternatively: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.ws.rs.Application</param-name>  
    <param-value>a.b.c.MyResourceConfig</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>